# jQuery UI Draggable output gives two different numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working on a project where I need to have a zoom-function. The user will then be able to drag the zoom around over the product picture.

In my implementation, when you drag the zoom around, it flickers the picture. I've come to the conclusion that it is due to jQuery outputting two numbers. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
imgZoom.draggable({
    drag:function(e, ui){
      var y = ui.position.top;
      var x = ui.position.left;
      //x = Math.floor(x);
      //y = Math.floor(y);
      var topZoom = parseInt(imgZoomImg.css('top'));
      var leftZoom = parseInt(imgZoomImg.css('left'));
      imgZoomImg.css({
        top:(-y*6) - topZoom,
        left:(-x*6) - leftZoom
      })
      console.log(topZoom)
    },
    containment:'.product-view-degree'
  });
```

This is the output from the console:

```
default.js:109 -153
default.js:109 -429
default.js:109 -147
default.js:109 -423
default.js:109 -141
default.js:109 -417
default.js:109 -135
default.js:109 -411
default.js:109 -129
default.js:109 -405
```

Edit: I've put it up on jsfiddler now: http://jsfiddle.net/640pfoq0/

Edit: After some help from a friend, I managed to rewrite it:

```
imgZoom.draggable({
    drag:function(e, ui){
      e.stopPropagation();

      var x = parseInt(imgZoom.css('top')) + 75;
      var y = parseInt(imgZoom.css('left')) + 75;


      imgZoomImg.css({
        top:(-x*3)+75,
        left:(-y*3)+150
      })

    },
    containment:'.product-view-degree'
});
```

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle to show the behaviour?

Comment: Ah yes, that might give a bigger picture :)
http://jsfiddle.net/640pfoq0/